# Persist $_POST data after a redirect

Tags: php, post, redirect

What is the best way to persist $_POST data before a redirect?

Imagine this situation: Page A has a data form, then we click in the submit button to send a $_POST request to the same page A.

If there are errors to display, it will be interesting to load the data again in the data form, preventing the user write all the text twice

Comment: Not sure if I understand. Well you should have for each data field something like this: if(isset($_POST['some_field_id'])) echo $_POST['some_field_id']; else echo '';

Comment: What part of your question concerns redirection?

Comment: If I have a data field with invalid value, I need to reload this data field. But this data field was present in the last section.   Example:  Page A (has the data field) --- redirect 302 ---> Page B (need to reload the data field)

Comment: Sorry by the english, I´m not a good writer in english

Comment: You could store the `$_POST` array in the `session` and later read it back in another page. But I am not sure if this is safe.

Comment: There is http 307, which redirects using the same method (e.g redirecting a post causes another post). not everything supports it, howerver.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late maybe, but here is a method anyway. (for anyone with the same question)

Lets say you have a page, "form.php"
If you POST your form to the page itself:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
  // action of the form will be "/path/on_your/webserver/to/form.php"
  // so it will POST to itself
  <input name="field_1" type="text" placeholder="Enter Text">
  <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Now if you click submit it will process any php code you have in your file.
If you want the text in the `<input name="field_1">` you entered to be there after the POST request you give the `<input>` field a value attribute and let PHP echo the posted value like this:

```
<input name="field_1" type="text" placeholder="Enter Text" 
value="<?php if isset($_POST) {echo $_POST['field_1'];}?>">
```

Now after you put text in the input field and click submit, the text will be in the field.

You probably already have this solution or another one. Note that if you are using this solution, the `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` if vulnerable to url-injection hacks. Take care and sanitise your variables where needed.